# How to map following string two prepetiy to map or array using typescript?

Tags: html, string, typescript

Is there any way to put this sting "Path" and "Value" put in an array map using typescript?

`String x =  "<html><body><a href="">ix3.log </a><a href="C:\docker_command.txt">docker_command.txt </a></body></html> "`

As example : array[] = [href][value]  = {{"C:\Documents\ix3.log" :"ix3.log"},{"C:\docker_command.txt":"docker_command.txt"} }

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you’re talking about is a typescript [Tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).  You want an array which can only have two values: the href and the file name, where both are strings.

```
type MyType = [string, string]

const myValue: MyType = ["C:\Documents\ix3.log", "ix3.log"];
```

You can then access the individual properties of the tuple by

```
const [href, fileName] = myValue;
```

Or

```
const href = myValue[0];
const fileName = myValue[1];
```